# Working with vectors in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm just kinda confused about a problem in my linear algebra textbook. Maybe one of you geniuses on here can help me out.

`There are two vectors in the plane that have a y-coordinate of 2 and form a 20 degree angle with the vector {1, 2}. Find them both and plot them.`

I attempted at using the formula for finding the angle between two vectors and reversing it to solve the unknown but I got a really weird number

(http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP394320g466b4idbhb72d0000650878cc013397gf?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=49&w=580.&h=58.)

If anyone could just point me in the right direction that would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you write a two dimensional vector then it is probably a better idea to use round parentheses: $\;(1,2)\;$ , and not $\;\{1,2\}\;$ , which most mathematicians would understand as the set containing the elements $\;1,2\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\;(x,2)\;$ be such a vector, then as $\;20^\circ=\frac\pi9\;\text{radians}\;$ , we get

$$\cos \frac\pi9=\frac{(x,2)\cdot(1,2)}{||(x,2)||\;||(1,2)||}=\frac{x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+4}\,\cdot\sqrt5}$$

Putting $\;\alpha:=\cos\frac\pi9\;$ and squaring, we get the quadratic:

$$5\alpha^2(x^2+4)=x^2+8x+16$$

Solve this now and find your $\;x$'s .